# how to use the Werkzeug debugger in postman?

Tags: python-3.x, postman, flask-restful, werkzeug

i am building a flask RESTapi and i am using postman to make http post requests to my api , i want to use the werkzeug debugger , but postman wont allow me to put in the debugging pin and debug the code from postman , what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Never needed any debugger for postman. This is not the tool you need the long blanket of code for one endpoint to test.
It gives a good option - console. I have never experienced any trouble this simple element didn't help me so far.

Comment: I am not talking about a debugger for postman .. i am talking about the handy werkzeug debugger that used to pop up in the browser ... While rendering template in flask ... Is there any way to use that debugger while developing api?

Comment: unfortunately in this case not.